# how do I handle an array differently using Javascript and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to create an array that pass one item waits for a response from my node server from a list.

My data input to JavaScript is from a text area in html then I am trying to send each line one at a time it can only send the next array item when my nodeJS has finished can anyone show me any example's or ways to post an array one item at a time.

instead of in one big chunk like I am getting currently.

```
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item
        socket.emit("dout", { message : msg[i] } );


    }
    // the old code
    // document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect("https://json2-c9-ashg1990.c9.io");
socket.on("news", function(data) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.hello);

});
// socket.emit("my other event", { message : "client emit" } );
</script>
```

my full html

```
<html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Welcome To ....</title>
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item
        socket.emit("dout", { message : msg[i] } );


    }
    // the old code
    // document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect("https://json2-c9-ashg1990.c9.io");
socket.on("news", function(data) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.hello);

});
// socket.emit("my other event", { message : "client emit" } );
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1>

<form>

<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>

<br>

<input type="button" value="show array" onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">

</form>

<br>

<textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. Can you please post `the old code` separately from what you have now?

Comment: the old code is this code and I am new to javascript hence the mess if you could point me in the right direction or what I am looking for i.e a name for the type of array function I want I tthink I may have to use callback()

Comment: I just cannot get what your code is doing and what you are trying to accomplish. 
Where do you use `textareaToArray`?
Where do you actually **send the array**? I can see only `showArray` function which is used nowhere.

Comment: I am sending the array to node js using the socket.emit function . I have edited the post with my html and node server

Answer (score 0):

Well, you code seems OK, except the regexp you use.
You should split the string using `\n` character. You are using `\n\r`, which is not a Windown line break character sequence.

Window character sequence is `\r\n`.

See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html

Comment: The regexp is **not** `\n\r`, it's `[\n\r]`. So, it's a correct one.